# Update UICollectionView height based on content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

UICollectionView height not updating properly based on content. How to update height

My code :

```
collectionViewArray.append(trimmedStrig!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.collectionViewArray.count == 1 {
                self.collectionViewHeight.constant = self.collectionView.contentSize.height + 50
                print(self.collectionViewHeight.constant)
            } else if self.collectionViewArray.count > 1 {
                self.collectionViewHeight.constant = self.collectionView.contentSize.height
                print(self.collectionViewHeight.constant)
            }
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }

//Fix collection view cell height and width
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)
}
```

When  create 1st cell it's not displaying that cell, that's why I added 50 and when cell entered into second row again it's not updating height, but when 2nd row 2nd cell created in that Time height updated. Why I don't know?

Comment: try to set collectionview height equal to top view height

Comment: @ Alexandr Kolesnik, I don't want to fix to top view height, because it's only just small part in my VC

Comment: But, based on content I'm updating my VC height I had scroll view

Comment: self.collectionViewHeight.constant = self.collectionViewArray.count * 50 self.view.layoutIfNeeded(). In that case don't forget to update layout after your constraints are updated

Comment: No, not updating the height

Comment: have you checked contentSize of your collectionView after reload? and collection view frame after reload?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196970/discussion-between-ios-and-alexandr-kolesnik).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one its may be helpful for you

```
self.collView.reloadData()
self.collView.performBatchUpdates({}) { (complition) in
            self.cnsHeightCollView.constant = self.collView.contentSize.height
        }
```

Comment: @iOS Please mark as correct answer if you fill its correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in code:-

```
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

- e.g.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
 {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)
      if self.collectionViewArray.count == 1 
      {
          self.collectionViewHeight.constant = self.collectionView.contentSize.height + 50
          print(self.collectionViewHeight.constant)
      }
      else if self.collectionViewArray.count > 1 
      {
           self.collectionViewHeight.constant = self.collectionView.contentSize.height
           print(self.collectionViewHeight.constant)
       }
            collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true //Here
            self.collectionView.reloadData()            
   }
```

Comment: Now try this latest one

Comment: Put your code into viewDidAppear() instead of dispachQueue.

Comment: Here when I click btn cell will be crated, so that's why I'm using queue, I write your code  in Btn action. But no use